# Incorrect Id return from MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a Stored Procedure that look like this

```
BEGIN
insert into `TheSomaProject`.`Projects` 
( `ProjectNr`, `MachineName`, `MachineNameEng`, `Type_Id`, 
  `SerialNr`, `Description`, `Created`, `CompanyId`, `MachineType` ) 
values 
( param_ProjectNr, param_MachineName, param_MachineNameEng, param_TypeId, 
  param_Serial, param_Description, NOW(), param_CompId, param_MachineType); 
SELECT last_insert_id(); 
END
```

But the return dosent give me the Id, it's looks like this 0x00000000. The C# code look like this

```
MySqlDataReader Reader;
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "CALL stp_InsertProject(@param_ProjectNr, @param_MachineName, @param_MachineNameEng, @param_TypeId, @param_Serial, @param_Description, @param_CompId, @param_MachineType);";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_ProjectNr", projectNr);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_MachineName", MachineName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_MachineNameEng", MachineNameEng);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_TypeId", TypeId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_Serial", SerialNr);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_Description", Description);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_CompId", CompanyId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param_MachineType", MachineType);
conn.Open();
Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["last_insert_id()"]);
}
conn.Close();
```

But if i try to use the same stp_InsertProject in phpMyAdmin i get the correct id back.

Comment: Firstly I would say incorrect usage of MySqlCommand for SP. [see section 25.2.3.1.12.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stored procedure does not return a result set with a column named 'last_insert_id()', thus using an `MySqlDataReader` will not work (as you expect).

Use `ExecuteScalar()` to get the result. Note that the value returned is actually a [64-bit integer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), so should use a `Int64` (or `long`) type to hold the result:

```
Int64 lastInsertId = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If you need to have a `Int32` variable, and thus risk the overflow if too many rows are inserted, make sure you don't directly cast to `Int32` (or `int`) as this will cause an `InvalidCastException` since the return type isn't really `Int32` but `Int64`. In this case use `Convert.ToInt32`. But I would really suggest that you use a 64 bit integer.

Comment: But i still dont the right result for some reason. It still looks like this 0x0000000000000013. Even if i try to convert it to something other than Int, the same result.

Comment: What do you mean it "looks like"? The 0x0000000000000013 is a perfectly valid integer, just in hex notation (it would be 19 in decimal notation). How do you output the value?

Comment: Right now im just using Breakpoint i VS2010, where i can se the values.

Comment: You can see them right there in the debugger (watch window, quick watch, tool tip). As I said, you (might) see the value in hex, rather than in decimal, but the value is there nevertheless.

Comment: I found the problem. VS2010 has change the value display to Hex instead of integer. I now works as i should. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Int64 i = (Int64)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: It just gives me an "Specified cast is not valid.".

Comment: -1 That won't work, because `last_insert_id()` returns a [_64_ bit integer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to get it with the separate query instead

```
//your code till the line "conn.Open();" goes here
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommadText="SELECT last_insert_id()";
Id=Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```